# Securtiy constraint for not logged user

Tags: java, security, servlets, wildfly

I want to lock access for authenticated users to login and register pages in my little project. I'm using a security domain in WildFly. Am I able to do that through my web.xml file?

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HtmlAuth</web-resource-name>
        <description>application security constraints</description>
        <url-pattern>/register.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/login.jsp</url-pattern>

        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>

    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

What should i put in

```
<auth-constraint>
</auth-constraint>
```

To guarantee access only for people who didn't login yet? Or how to redirect them?